# Issues Plotting Time Series Analysis

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series, k-means

I am trying to plot k means clustering for Time Series data I have run. I am clustering the FIPS codes by their number of Covid cases per day for a years worth of data. I am struggling to plot to time series data by cluster. I would like there to be one plot per cluster with each plot showing the time series data for the FIP codes assigned to the cluster being plotted. I  clustered using *TS Learn's TimeSeriesKmeans* with Euclidean Distance, I am not sure it matters what package I used for clustering. The example code I was given for plotting has it's starting data as a series, where I am starting from a data frame - I think this where the problem starts. I don't think I am calling to the right elements when trying to plot. For my data frame each column a different FIPS code, the index is a datetime index (freq = day), and as a I mentioned each value is the number of Covid cases per day (the data frame has been smoothed and scaled appropriately).

X1: is a toy data set from my data, with

X = the transpose the values of the df, which is what I cluster

y_pred = clusters assigned to each FIPS code

```
[IN]: X1 
[Out]:

Fips         40025.0     21201.0     30061.0     46021.0      2013.0
date                    
2020-08-08  0.000861    0.001292    0.000287    0.001177    0.001636
2020-08-09  0.001147    0.001290    0.000344    0.001204    0.001663
2020-08-10  0.001431    0.001288    0.000401    0.001231    0.001689
2020-08-11  0.001801    0.001286    0.000457    0.001258    0.001715
2020-08-12  0.002170    0.001285    0.000514    0.001285    0.001713
2020-08-13  0.002537    0.001283    0.000570    0.001311    0.001711
2020-08-14  0.002904    0.001281    0.000626    0.001338    0.001708
2020-08-15  0.003270    0.001280    0.000682    0.001365    0.001706
2020-08-16  0.003635    0.001278    0.000738    0.001392    0.001704
2020-08-17  0.003999    0.001276    0.000794    0.001418    0.001702

[IN]: # transpose values - b/c of how my df is set up this 
is the only way I could get it to cluster on the right values    
X=X1.transpose().values
X

[OUT]:
array([[0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        8.10149545e-05, 8.09934723e-05, 8.09720014e-05],
       ...,
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        7.69058567e-02, 7.69331924e-02, 7.69605135e-02],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        1.49917884e-01, 1.50472565e-01, 1.51026953e-01],
       [0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, 0.00000000e+00, ...,
        8.19101697e-02, 8.19086985e-02, 8.19072280e-02]])

[IN]: # set up k means model and fit_predict
km = TimeSeriesKMeans(n_clusters=25, verbose=True, random_state=0)
y_pred = km.fit_predict(X)

[IN]: # this is where I am struggling*****
# I got this code for plotting from an example in the documentation for the package. 

plt.figure()
# range = # clusters
for yi in range(25):
    plt.subplot(5, 5, yi + 1)
    for xx in X[y_pred == yi]:
        plt.plot(xx, "k-", alpha=.2)
    plt.plot(km.cluster_centers_[yi].ravel(), "r-")
    # I changed the x axis to be dates but I think this is the issue
    plt.xlim([datetime.date(2020, 1, 20), datetime.date(2021, 5, 4)])
    plt.ylim(0, 300)
    plt.text(0.55, 0.85,'Cluster %d' % (yi + 1),
             transform=plt.gca().transAxes)
    if yi == 1:
        plt.title("Euclidean $k$-means")
```

[OUT]:is what is happening
[image]

As you can see nothing prints in the plot. If anyone has any ideas I would greatly appreciate the help! Thank you!

Comment: I found it a bit hard to follow your problem. You may want to sharpen the explanations (if the clustering is not your problem, it may just distract talking about it). I also always appreciate it if you generate a toy example rather than pointing me to the original data. And finally, you may want to describe exactly how it should look like =)

Comment: Well I am trying to plot clustering data so that why I am talking about it. But I will work on sharping the question!

Comment: @max I re-worked my question, please tell me if it now makes sense. Thank you!